# sending data to another website and receive result

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

If i have a `website1.com` and `website2.com`, can I send data ( ex: value from input ) from `website2.com` to `website1.com` and receive result? with no page refresh or redirect. I'd like to use only `javascript` & `ajax`, no `PHP` or `jQuery`. If it is possible give me an example how to do it.

I thought about creating an `script` element ( with javascript) on `website2.com` with src like : `website1.com?data=<value from input>`, and when `script` element loads the src, it will show me an result, but maybe there is a better option to do this.

PS: I will have more separated datas to send.

Note: this is not XSS, just a public project for websites, which will need to update datas every `x` minutes and to send some data to `website1`.

Thanks.

Comment: You want to execute a javascript from website2 with a javascript from website1?

Comment: No. the javascript on website2 is loaded from website1, then when user want to send some data, the data need to be sent to website1 and then website2 need to receive result ( ex: your data successful submitted, or something like that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since XmlHttpRequest does not work cross-domain, you have to use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). Basically, this is adding a script tag dynamically as you're suggesting to do. Then, the server uses your GET datas, does whatever it wants, and usually "prints" a callback function.

When you call a file using the script tag, it will evaluate everything displayed. This is why, if, on the server side, you're doing :

```
<?php
echo 'alert(1);';
?>
```

This will be evaluated as javascript. You can then easily understand how to use a callback function (another GET parameter).

Also, in jQuery, there is an option called 'jsonp' when you call [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (using "callback" as default GET parameter, but can be changed).

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not completely clear, but in general when you have to do cross-site AJAX you have to use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

Answer (score 0):

You could have some XSS issues but it is possible you could use ajaxgold. It is an pretty easy manner to send pretty much everything over.

Call send to website2

```
postDataReturnText( 'http://website2.com', 'data=bla', getResult );
```

Return the result

```
function getResult( text ) {}
```